# Very slow performance in Django with remote Oracle server

Tags: django, oracle

I'm running a raw SQL query in Django to a remote Oracle Server. The query is very long and **it took a minute and a half to complete**, but if I do the same query using the Oracle SQL Server program, the query runs in less than a second.

Why is there so much difference in performance? How can I speed up my query in Django?

BTW, I'm using the Django's dev server and the profile toolbar (Django 1.5).

**UPDATE:** Here is the query in Django

```
holidays_filter = ''
if filters['holidays'] == 'exclude':
    holidays_filter = 'AND FECHAS.FESTIVO = 0'

hp_inner_join = ''
if filters['hour-mode'] == 'hp-sector-ps':
    hp_inner_join = """
        INNER JOIN
        EGW.RHP_CELLSEC_PS HPCELLPS
        ON UCELL2.DIA = HPCELLPS.DIA
           AND UCELL2.HORA = HPCELLPS.HORA
           AND UCELL2.RNC = HPCELLPS.RNC
           AND UCELL2.UTRANCELL = HPCELLPS.CELLID
        """
elif filters['hour-mode'] == 'hp-rnc-ps':    
    hp_inner_join = """
        INNER JOIN
        EGW.RHP_RNC_PS HPRNCPS
        ON UCELL2.DIA = HPRNCPS.DIA
           AND UCELL2.HORA = HPRNCPS.HORA
           AND UCELL2.RNC = HPRNCPS.RNC
        """

sql = """
  SELECT CUSTOM.DIA, CUSTOM.HORA,
         ROUND(CUSTOM.TRAF_CS57 + CUSTOM.TRAF_CS64 + CUSTOM.TRAF_CS12 + CUSTOM.TRAF_CSAMR12200 + CUSTOM.TRAF_CSAMR7950 + CUSTOM.TRAF_CSAMR5900 + CUSTOM.TRAF_CSAMR4750, 1) AS TRAFICO_CS_ERL,
         ROUND(CUSTOM.A + CUSTOM.B + CUSTOM.C + CUSTOM.D, 1) AS TRAFICO_PS_ERL

    FROM (SELECT TOTAL.DIA, TOTAL.HORA, TOTAL.RNC, TOTAL.UTRANCELL,
                 CASE
                     WHEN TOTAL.PMSAMPLESCS12RABESTABLISH = 0
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE TOTAL.PMSUMCS12RABESTABLISH / TOTAL.PMSAMPLESCS12RABESTABLISH
                 END AS TRAF_CS12,
                 CASE
                     WHEN TOTAL.PMSAMPLESBESTCS57RABESTABLISH = 0
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE TOTAL.PMSUMBESTCS57RABESTABLISH / TOTAL.PMSAMPLESBESTCS57RABESTABLISH
                 END AS TRAF_CS57,
                 CASE
                     WHEN TOTAL.PMSAMPLESBESTCS64RABESTABLISH = 0
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE TOTAL.PMSUMBESTCS64RABESTABLISH / TOTAL.PMSAMPLESBESTCS64RABESTABLISH
                 END AS TRAF_CS64,
                 CASE
                     WHEN TOTAL.PMSAMPLBESTAMR12200RABESTABLIS = 0
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE TOTAL.PMSUMBESTAMR12200RABESTABLISH / TOTAL.PMSAMPLBESTAMR12200RABESTABLIS
                 END AS TRAF_CSAMR12200,
                 CASE
                     WHEN TOTAL.PMSAMPLBESTAMR7950RABESTABLISH = 0
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE TOTAL.PMSUMBESTAMR7950RABESTABLISH / TOTAL.PMSAMPLBESTAMR7950RABESTABLISH
                 END AS TRAF_CSAMR7950,
                 CASE
                     WHEN TOTAL.PMSAMPLBESTAMR5900RABESTABLISH = 0
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE TOTAL.PMSUMBESTAMR5900RABESTABLISH / TOTAL.PMSAMPLBESTAMR5900RABESTABLISH
                 END AS TRAF_CSAMR5900,
                 CASE
                     WHEN TOTAL.PMSAMPLBESTAMR4750RABESTABLISH = 0
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE TOTAL.PMSUMBESTAMR4750RABESTABLISH / TOTAL.PMSAMPLBESTAMR4750RABESTABLISH
                 END AS TRAF_CSAMR4750,

                 CASE
                     WHEN TOTAL.PMSAMPLEBESTDCHPSINTRABESTABLI = 0
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE TOTAL.PMSUMBESTDCHPSINTRABESTABLISH / TOTAL.PMSAMPLEBESTDCHPSINTRABESTABLI
                 END AS A,
                 CASE
                     WHEN TOTAL.PMSAMPLEFACHPSINTRABESTABLISH = 0
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE TOTAL.PMSUMFACHPSINTRABESTABLISH / TOTAL.PMSAMPLEFACHPSINTRABESTABLISH
                 END AS B,
                 CASE
                     WHEN TOTAL.PMSAMPBESTPSHSADCHRABESTABLISH = 0
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE TOTAL.PMSUMBESTPSHSADCHRABESTABLISH / TOTAL.PMSAMPBESTPSHSADCHRABESTABLISH
                 END AS C,
                 CASE
                     WHEN TOTAL.PMSAMPLBESTPSEULRABESTABLI = 0
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE TOTAL.PMSUMBESTPSEULRABESTABLISH / TOTAL.PMSAMPLBESTPSEULRABESTABLI
                 END AS D

            FROM (SELECT UCELL2.DIA, UCELL2.HORA, UCELL2.RNC, UCELL2.UTRANCELL,
                         SUM(UCELL2.PMSAMPLESCS12RABESTABLISH) AS PMSAMPLESCS12RABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL2.PMSUMCS12RABESTABLISH) AS PMSUMCS12RABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL3.PMSAMPLESBESTCS57RABESTABLISH) AS PMSAMPLESBESTCS57RABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL3.PMSUMBESTCS57RABESTABLISH) AS PMSUMBESTCS57RABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL3.PMSAMPLESBESTCS64RABESTABLISH) AS PMSAMPLESBESTCS64RABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL3.PMSUMBESTCS64RABESTABLISH) AS PMSUMBESTCS64RABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL3.PMSUMBESTDCHPSINTRABESTABLISH) AS PMSUMBESTDCHPSINTRABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL3.PMSAMPLEBESTDCHPSINTRABESTABLI) AS PMSAMPLEBESTDCHPSINTRABESTABLI,
                         SUM(UCELL3.PMSUMFACHPSINTRABESTABLISH) AS PMSUMFACHPSINTRABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL3.PMSAMPLEFACHPSINTRABESTABLISH) AS PMSAMPLEFACHPSINTRABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL3.PMSUMBESTPSHSADCHRABESTABLISH) AS PMSUMBESTPSHSADCHRABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL3.PMSAMPBESTPSHSADCHRABESTABLISH) AS PMSAMPBESTPSHSADCHRABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL3.PMSUMBESTPSEULRABESTABLISH) AS PMSUMBESTPSEULRABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL3.PMSAMPLBESTPSEULRABESTABLI) AS PMSAMPLBESTPSEULRABESTABLI,
                         SUM(UCELL4.PMSAMPLBESTAMR12200RABESTABLIS) AS PMSAMPLBESTAMR12200RABESTABLIS,
                         SUM(UCELL4.PMSUMBESTAMR12200RABESTABLISH) AS PMSUMBESTAMR12200RABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL4.PMSAMPLBESTAMR7950RABESTABLISH) AS PMSAMPLBESTAMR7950RABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL4.PMSUMBESTAMR7950RABESTABLISH) AS PMSUMBESTAMR7950RABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL4.PMSAMPLBESTAMR5900RABESTABLISH) AS PMSAMPLBESTAMR5900RABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL4.PMSUMBESTAMR5900RABESTABLISH) AS PMSUMBESTAMR5900RABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL4.PMSAMPLBESTAMR4750RABESTABLISH) AS PMSAMPLBESTAMR4750RABESTABLISH,
                         SUM(UCELL4.PMSUMBESTAMR4750RABESTABLISH) AS PMSUMBESTAMR4750RABESTABLISH

                    FROM EGW.TF_RNC_RAN_UCELL2 UCELL2

                         INNER JOIN
                         EGW.TF_RNC_RAN_UCELL3 UCELL3
                         ON UCELL2.DIA = UCELL3.DIA
                            AND UCELL2.HORA = UCELL3.HORA
                            AND UCELL2.RNC = UCELL3.RNC
                            AND UCELL2.MO = UCELL3.MO
                            AND UCELL2.MINUTO = UCELL3.MINUTO
                            AND UCELL2.UTRANCELL = UCELL3.UTRANCELL

                         INNER JOIN
                         EGW.TF_RNC_RAN_UCELL4 UCELL4
                         ON UCELL2.DIA = UCELL4.DIA
                            AND UCELL2.HORA = UCELL4.HORA
                            AND UCELL2.RNC = UCELL4.RNC
                            AND UCELL2.MO = UCELL4.MO
                            AND UCELL2.MINUTO = UCELL4.MINUTO
                            AND UCELL2.UTRANCELL = UCELL4.UTRANCELL

                         INNER JOIN
                         JANO.FECHAS FECHAS
                         ON UCELL2.DIA = FECHAS.FECHA

                         """ + hp_inner_join + """

                   WHERE UCELL2.DIA BETWEEN TO_DATE(%s, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(%s, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                     AND UCELL2.HORA BETWEEN %s AND %s
                     AND UCELL2.RNC = %s
                     AND UCELL2.UTRANCELL = %s
                     AND FECHAS.DIASEM IN (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) 
                     """ + holidays_filter + """

                GROUP BY UCELL2.DIA, UCELL2.HORA, UCELL2.RNC, UCELL2.UTRANCELL) TOTAL) CUSTOM

ORDER BY CUSTOM.DIA, CUSTOM.HORA        
"""
```

Comment: Do you mean sql*plus?  How many rows of data are returned?  Are you sure the query is EXACT?  Are bind parameters being used in one vs. the other.  Please show your table structure, sql*plus run, and sql code from your app server.  If you run the same query multiple times from each environment, are the execution times consistent?

Comment: Good point. The queries where not exactly the same. In Django I was using bind parameters while in Oracle SQL Server (I suppose it uses sqlplus in the background) the "parameters" where hard coded in the query. I did a test modifying the Django query with hard coded parameters and the performance improve a lot. How can I get the same performance using bind parameters in Django?

Comment: What do your models look like?

Comment: I don't have any models in my app. It just do queries to a db to present a visual representation of the data with charts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I found the solution. In Django all binded parameters are defined as strings (%s) so a lot of implicit conversion is made when the parameter is, for instance, a number. The solution is to explicitly typecast them as number using the function `TO_NUMBER(%s)` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Cool.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should run both queries with an explain plan to see the differences.  My guess is that in the literal parameter case, an index is being used, and in the bound parameter case it may not be used. IF you can see the difference between the two, you may need to add a "hint" clause to your select statement to force the correct index to be picked.  You can read about hints [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/hintsref.htm)

If you are using sqlplus, you can turn on autotrace to show you the explain plan and execution statistics, example:

```
SQL> set autotrace on
SQL> set linesize 200
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> spool foo.log
SQL> select count(*) from ucbcust; -- this is just a test table in my database. replace with your SQL.
SQL>   ... output shows...
SQL>  spool off


Output would look something like this (obviously, different for your query):



  Execution Plan
    ----------------------------------------------------------                                  
    Plan hash value: 1527793343                                                                                           ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------          
    | Id  | Operation             | Name                   | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |            

     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |                        |     1 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 
                                                                                                    |   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE       |                        |     1 |            |
                                                                                                       |   2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| UCBCUST_CUST_KEY_INDEX |  2088 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01

```
|                                                                                                    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Statistics

              0  recursive calls                                                                                                                                                                            
              0  db block gets                                                                                                                                                                              
             17  consistent gets                                                                                                                                                                            
              0  physical reads                                                                                                                                                                             
              0  redo size                                                                                                                                                                                  
            343  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client                                                                                                                                                           
            364  bytes received via SQL*Net from client                                                                                                                                                     
              2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client                                                                                                                                                          
              0  sorts (memory)                                                                                                                                                                             
              0  sorts (disk)                                                                                                                                                                               
              1  rows processed
```

To execute the parameterized query in a similar fashion in sqlplus, you will need to define a variable as a placeholder, example:

```
SQL> variable foo number
SQL> exec :foo := 1000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select :foo from dual
  2  /

      :FOO
----------
      1000
```

So, in your query, replace all the "%*" parameters with a variable and run in Sqlplus to see the execution details.  Hopefully, with those tools, you will see the difference in the execution plans.

Comment: When I try tu run `SQL> SET autotrace ON;` I get the following:
`SP2-0613: Unable to verify PLAN_TABLE format or existence
SP2-0611: Error enabling EXPLAIN report
SP2-0618: Cannot find the Session Identifier.  Check PLUSTRACE role is enabled
SP2-0611: Error enabling STATISTICS report`

Comment: You don't have the explain_plan schemas and tables installed on your database.  check with your DBA, if you have one.

Comment: I found the problem, see mi answer below. Thanks a lot for your help man